# Use Julia to read a list of paths from a txt and open it

Tags: csv, julia

I have a txt file with some csv paths, for instance the file Links.txt which contains

```
/home/someone/something/aplha1.csv    
/home/someone/something/aplha2.csv
/home/someone/something/aplha3.csv
/home/someone/something/aplha4.csv
```

I would like to read the file line by line using Julia Lang and then for each line to read the csv file. I am using the below code

```
open("Links.txt") do f
  for line in eachline(f)
  rawnames = readcsv(line)
  println("read line: ", line)
  end
end
```

Unfortunately I am getting error

```
ERROR: opening file /home/someone/something/aplha1.csv
: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

thx!

Comment: what happens when you execute `cat /home/someone/something/aplha1.csv` from the command line?

Comment: Hey Paul, it returns the content of aplha1.csv without any error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is `line` contains the end-of-line character at the end. Try changing it to

```
readcsv(chomp(line))
```

Comment: Note that while it's hard to arrange from the shell, file names on most UNIX systems *can* actually contain newlines, so asking for the contents of a file called `"/home/someone/something/aplha1.csv\n"` is not actually ridiculous.